# Can't open websocket from React app through NGINX

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I have a dockerized React app `frontend` that is served through NGINX:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY ./build /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

`.build` is my React web app. `default.conf` contains this:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://api:8080;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

My webapp makes requests against another linked container named `api`, so all `/api` calls are proxy passed to the `api` container.

So far, so good.

Problem comes when I try to open a websocket. Websocket server is listening also in `api` container, but in port `8081`.

In my code, I have this:

```
const socket = openSocket('http://api:8081'); //openSocket is from socket.io library
```

But, in my Chrome console, I'm getting `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOVED`.

How can I configure NGINX in order to proxy pass this request to `api` container?

Comment: I believe that `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOVED` means the domain name `api` can't be resolved. How did you run the `frontend` container? docker-compose or the `docker run`?

Comment: I'm running the frontend with docker. It is in the same docker network that api. In fact, when I sh inside frontend container, I can ping api successfully. Also, webapp is able to fetch data from `api` via REST API, but not connect to websocket.

Comment: Which URL did you use when accessing `api`? And how does the frontend container expose its port 80? I guess the `http://api:8080` also can't be accessed in your browser. If so, port 8081 of `api` needs to be proxied by the frontend.

Comment: REST API is available at `http://api:8080/api` and I want the websocket api to be available at `http://api:8081`. How can I proxy 8081 of api by the frotend?